# Si no escribo nada en la pantalla emergente y directamente hago click en "Aceptar" con JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java

Si hago clic en la opción "Aceptar" en la pantalla emergente de JOptionPane.showInputDialog, sin haber introducido ningún dato, me salta un error.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hacer para que, en lugar de saltarme el error, me devolviera otra vez la misma pantalla emergente solicitándome introducir datos por teclado?

Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de hacerlo es poniendo el `JOptionPane` en un bucle infinito y verificando con una condición si el usuario ingreso o no algo

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class solucion {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String entrada;

        while(true){

            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca un texto");

            //En caso que la entrada sea vacia
            if(entrada.isEmpty()){

                entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Introduzca un texto");
            }
            else{
                
                //En caso que haya ingresado algo
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("El texto que usted ingreso es: "+entrada);
    }
}
```

Comment: Espero te sirva de algo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta Daniel Murillo.

Comment: Estamos para ayudar ;)